# Select fields with dynamic choice values in python wtforms

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, wtforms

How do you make a select field with dynamic choices in python wtforms. I read almost everything published. And i really understand this:

1. do not add choices in class form, because is studied only one time and will give you problems on validate in this way: `category = SelectField('Category', coerce=int)`
2. coerce int to be sure it will be readed correctly in this way: `category = SelectField('Category', choices=[], coerce=int)`
3. add choices on endpoint in this way: `form.category.choices = categories`

Now, this is the problem:

1. If you do not add choices choices=[], it raises error NoneType
2. If you add choices, it do not validate because "not valid"

my code:

```
author=SelectField('author', choices=[], default=1)
```

```
Cursor.execute(source, 1)
choices_source=Cursor.fetchall()
    form.source.choices= [(c[0], c[1]) for c in choices_source]
```

is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `choices` attribute after the form has been instantiated seems to work:

```
import wtforms
from werkzeug.datastructures import MultiDict


class AuthorForm(wtforms.Form):

    author = wtforms.SelectField('author', coerce=int, default=1)


authors = [(1, 'Amy Tan'), (2, 'Michael Chabon')]
af = AuthorForm()
af.author.choices = authors
for field in af: 
    print(field)


af = AuthorForm(formdata=MultiDict([('author', '1')]))
af.author.choices = authors
if not af.validate():
    print(af.errors)
else:
    print(af.data)
```

Output:

```html
<select id="author" name="author"><option selected value="1">Amy Tan</option><option value="2">Michael Chabon</option></select>
```

```
{'author': 1}
```